# Counterexample to Pólya's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

It is known that [Polya's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polya_conjecture) is false and the smallest counter-example is about $10^9$.

Assuming that we are searching for a counter-example not knowing that it exists. What useful information can I use to speed up my search ?

**Motivation :** If we try brute force on an (i7), 32 bits system with 8 GB of RAM, we are looking to a hour of computation but this was done fifty years ago on a very slow machine, so they used some fancy mathematical techniques which I do not know of.

**How my brute force search works :**

First I have $L$ a large list of primes (up to $10^{10}$ for example).

to calculate $\Omega(n)$ the number of divisors of $n$ I look of a prime $p$ that divides $n$ and then calculate $\Omega(n)=\Omega(n/p)+1$.

The summatory function is done by a simple while loop.

Comment: Are you able to access Haselgrove's article, cited in the wikipedia entry above? That may give you some pointers. http://dx.doi.org/10.1112%2FS0025579300001480

Comment: The step where you look for a prime dividing $n$ looks like an obvious place for optimization: if you compute the original list $L$ using Eratosthenes sieve or something similar, it also gives you a prime divisor of each composite for free, you just need to store this information.

Comment: (Or maybe better, compute $\Omega(n)$ directly at the spot where you mark $n$ as composite.)

Comment: @j.c. I have seen Lehman's paper but it was too hard for me, I couldn't see how he employed all those theorem in his algorithm.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you but this does not reduce the running time much (neither the RAM needed), I believe that there is some pure maths behind the search.

Comment: That may well be, nevertheless you mention an hour of computation, whereas computing the list of primes below $10^{10}$ with a sieve takes a few seconds, and making it compute the parity of $\Omega(n)$ on the fly shouldn’t take much more than that. This sounds to me like an improvement by two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Anyway, the counterexample below $10^9$ wasn’t found by Haselgrove, but by Lehman. His article is here http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2003890 , and it includes a description of his computation method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Lehman's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2003890) is very clear about what he is doing. One can express $L(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\lambda(n)$ as a rather short sum whose terms are expressible easily from the values of $\mu(m)$, $\lambda(k)$, $L(y)$ for $m,k,y$ much smaller than $x$.

The starting identity is (4) in the paper, namely
$$ \sum_{m\leq x}L(x/m) = \lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor. $$
This can be proved as follows:
$$ \sum_{m\leq x}L(x/m) = \sum_{m\leq x}\sum_{n\leq x/m}\lambda(n) = \sum_{mn\leq x}\lambda(n)=\sum_{k\leq x}\sum_{n\mid k}\lambda(n).$$
The inner sum is a multiplicative function in $k$, and on a prime power $p^r$ it is zero or one according to whether $r$ is even or odd. Hence the inner sum is zero or one according to whether $k$ is a square or not, so
$$ \sum_{m\leq x}L(x/m) = \sum_{\substack{k\leq x\\k=\square}}1=\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor.$$

This formula can be refined/generalized to yield similar (more complicated but for computational purposes more effective) identities, and the paper makes use of them. The general method is called "Dirichlet's hyperbola method'', and you can learn about it in number theory textbooks.

In short, Lehman's paper utilizes basic multiplicative number theory in a clever way. With a little effort you can understand all the details.